# Scheduling optimization with multiple constraints

Tags: optimization, job-scheduling

I have faced with a scheduling of `N` jobs which each of them has a release time, deadline and value. There is two type of constraints:

1. hard constraint which means I must schedule this set of jobs such that all of them meet their deadlines; and
2. soft constraint which means I prefer to schedule jobs in decreasing order of their values.

I know without considering soft constraint there exists an optimal scheduling algorithm called EDF (earliest deadline first) which schedules job with earliest deadline in each step. This problem satisfies Optimal substructure and Greedy Choice Properties which results in greedy algorithm become optimal solution.

Now, the question is: is there any solution which consider soft constraint as well as hard one? How we can prove its optimality?

I have thought about variant knapsack problem and nurse scheduling algorithms but unfortunately do not find any idea or solution yet.

it is worth noting that:

. jobs are preemptible which means jobs can be divided and executed in one time unit slices

Comment: You don't explicitly state it, but do you mean there is only one machine?

Comment: @Codor yes, there is only one processor

Comment: I don't fully understand it - without the soft constraints, does EDF solve the decision problem alone without an objective?

Comment: @Codor without soft constraint EDF solve the problem such that hard constraint satisfied